# Name validation regex for email header

Tags: php, regex, email, security, email-headers

I have a contact form, user supplies name and last name in separate fields. Server side it is used to form From header, like

```
From: $name $lastname <mailer@mydomain.com>
```

I have seen a lot of suggestions to use something like A-Za-z, but there are a lot of names containing characters outside latin alphabet. What would be the regex to allow foreign alphabet names, while keeping it secure from email injection?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Maybe `\p{L}+`, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php and use anchors. Are you checking `$name` and `$lastname` individually? Updating with your current code would be useful.

Comment: simple: don't use php's mail() for sending stuff. use a proper package like phpmailer or swiftmailer and let THEM worry about header injection. php mail() is mickey-mouse garbage, and shouldn't be used even for basic debugging/testing.

Comment: $name and $lastname are separate variables. I don't have any validation yet , I only thought about allow A-Za-z-', but like I said, it will not allow foreign characters. This is for a WordPress website and I'm using its wp_mail function. I don't know if it offers any protection, I have to check it.

Comment: Fiddle around with `^[\p{L}\h'-]+$`.

Comment: That seems to work, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Some people have only one name, such as Stack Overflow user sai (https://s.ai/iaq)
2. Many Hispanic people have multiple surnames, like Juan Pablo Fernández de Calderón García-Iglesias
3. Some given names are compound words, such as "Billy Bob"
4. Some surnames are compound words, such as "Vaughn Williams"
5. Some names are very short, like Po Ng or Malcolm X
6. Some people have symbols as names, such as The Artist (formerly known as Prince)
7. Some names include dashes, or apostrophes
8. Some people have unique names (that won't appear in lists of names), like D'Brickashaw Ferguson

So, the regex would be `/.+/`

If you're trying to prevent email addresses as names, I would find a good email address validator and make sure a name does not contain an email address

Comment: I just want to prevent any malicious stuff. For example I can't allow user to supply a name  like "name <email@domain.com>" as it would break my From header.

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk ok then use a good email address validator, like Apache's, and make sure name does not contain an email address